# What is the codomain of the function which inputs a set and outputs a vector whose entries are elements of that set?

Tags: functions

Consider the mapping $m$ whose domain is a totally ordered set $S=\mathcal{P}(\{1,\pi,e\})\backslash \varnothing$ (where $\mathcal{P}$ represents the power set) and whose output is a vector where each component is an element of $S$.

$m(\{1,\pi,e \}) = [1,\pi,e]$

$m(\{1,e\}) =[1,e]$

Normally I would write $m:S\to ?$, but I don't know what the codomain is, since the output is in one of  $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k=1,2,3$.

What is the codomain of $m$?

Edit: Follow up: Really I want to extend this to a set where S consists of a list of any $n$ real numbers. Then I guess the codomain is $\mathbb{R}\cup\mathbb{R}^2\cup\mathbb{R}^2\cup\ldots \cup \mathbb{R}^n $.

Comment: You can say the co-domain is the set of all $1,2$, and $3$ dimensional vectors with component entries from the set $\{1,\pi,e\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the mapping even well-defined?  Is

$$m(\{1,e\} )=[1,e]\ {\rm or}\ m(\{1,e\})=[e,1]$$

In the domain as you've described it,

{1,e}={e,1}

but this subset will need to map to only one of $[1,e]$ and $[e,1]$.  If you wish you could redefine the domain to be all *ordered* subsets (permutations) of

$$A=\{1, e, \pi\}$$

and then the mapping makes sense as a function.  The codomain then is just $A\cup A^2\cup A^3$.

Comment: Thanks, I made it ordered.